# How to return result from Cypress function after set

Tags: cypress

I have the following code:

```js
function getValues(date)
{
  let totalValue=-10;
  cy.visit('http://localhost/page1');  
  cy.get(".total").then((span)=> 
  {
    console.log("Values: "+span.text())
    totalValue=span.text()        
  }
  )
  //.then(()=> totalValue);
  return totalValue;
}
```

I would like to get the value of the element so I use this:

```
it('Testing values',()=>
{
  var totalValues=getValues(startDate)
  console.log("Total values: "+ totalValues)
}
```

Unfortunately, it never waits for the variable to be set.

Either I get this `-10` (when I use the `return`) or `undefined` (when I use `then`) as results and the order is incorrect:

> Total values: -10
>
> Values: 2.5

How could I force the execution to wait until the correct value is set?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an alias to store the value, but as already mentioned you have to access with `.then()` in the test

```js
function getValues(date) {
  let totalValue = -10;
  cy.visit('http://localhost/page1');  
  cy.get(".total")
    .then((span) => { 
      totalValue = span.text()
      cy.wrap(totalValue).as('totalValues')  // set alias value, 
                                             // must be inside .then()
    })  
}

it('Testing values', () => {
  getValues(startDate)
  cy.get('@totalValues').then(totalValues => {
    console.log("Total values: "+ totalValues)
  })
})
```

**Exception to using .then()**

You can use `before()` block in conjunction with alias to avoid using `.then()`, but it's a specific pattern.

```js
function getValues(date) {
  let totalValue = -10;
  cy.visit('http://localhost/page1');  
  cy.get(".total")
    .then((span) => { 
      totalValue = span.text()

      // will put totalValue on the "this" scope
      cy.wrap(totalValue).as('totalValues')  
    })  
}

before(() => {
  getValues(startDate)  // calling in before hook resolves all asynchronous calls
})

it('Testing values', function() {           // must use a function() format 
   
  // your value is a property of "this"
  console.log("Total values: " + this.totalValues)  

})
```

Answer (score 2):

With a plain JS function, return the last internal command and use `.then()` on the return value.

```js
function getValues(date) {
  cy.visit('http://localhost/page1');  
  return cy.get(".total").then((span) => span.text())
}

it('Testing values', () => {
  getValues(startDate).then(totalValues => {
    console.log("Total values: "+ totalValues)
  })
})
```

Or create a custom command

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getValues', (date) => {
  cy.visit('http://localhost/page1');  
  cy.get(".total").then((span) => span.text())  // does not need an explicit return
})

it('Testing values', () => {
  cy.getValues(startDate).then(totalValues => {
    console.log("Total values: "+ totalValues)
  })
})
```

If you want `var totalValues = ...` in the test, there's no way to do it. You always need a `.then()` because the value is obtained asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

The mixture of async(cypress) and sync code is the reason for the wrong order of logging.

In the scope of what you shared, here is what you can use to have the logging in the correct order. I'm not sure where the `startDate` or where else you plan on using or the html you'll use the `getValues()` function.

Here is the spec [file](https://github.com/jjhelguero/cypress-examples/blob/main/cypress/integration/syncAsyncLoggingOrder.md).

```html
<div class="total">2.5</div>
```

```js
function getValues(date) {
  let totalValue = -10
  return cy
    .get(".total")
    .invoke("text")
    .then((value) => cy.log("Value: " + value))
}

getValues().then((totalValues) => {
  cy.log("Total values: " + totalValues)
})
```